# Unable to consume an Angular service from a Controller

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs

So I've done extensive research and read many tutorials but I can't find a straightforward answer to what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'm simply trying to access a JSON object stored at JSON-Generator.com and stick it in a table and repeat it. Sounds simple enough but it seems there many different ways to do this and all the sources leave out the one piece of info I need.

if I console.log eventsService inside the controller it returns a constructor, if I console.log eventsService.data it returns undefined.

How do I access the data returned from $http in my controller?

```
// CONTROLLERS


app.controller('currentTradeshowsController', ['$scope', 'eventsService', function($scope, eventsService){


  $scope.events = eventsService.data;


}]);


    // SERVICES


app.service('eventsService',function($http){

  var eventsUrl = 'http://www.json-generator.com/j/bVWJaYaWoO?indent=4';


  $http({method: 'GET', url: eventsUrl}).
    success(function(data){
      // not sure what to write here....
      return data;

    })

    .error(function(){
      console.log('ah shit');
    })



});
```

Comment: Is your app code served off of JSON-Generator.com?  If not, then you're probably running into cross-domain restrictions of the browser. You'll want to make a JSONP call instead of a get call.

Comment: you are not returning anything from the service, that is the problem

Comment: I believe JSON-Generator does JSONP somehow. Didn't have an issue in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, `$http` call is asynchronous, so you probably want to use promises to load the data correctly into scope variable

second - you need to return something from the service to make it work outside of the service declaration function

**controller**

```
app.controller('currentTradeshowsController', function($scope, eventsService){
    eventsService.getData().then(function(data) {
        $scope.events = data;
    });
});
```

**service**

```
app.service('eventsService',function($http){
    var eventsUrl = 'http://www.json-generator.com/j/bVWJaYaWoO?indent=4';

    return {
        getData: function() {
            return $http.get(eventsUrl);
        }
    }
});
```

`$http.get` is a shorthand for GET request, and it returns a promise, so you can simply use it with `.then` in the controller